# Library for drawing musical notes

Tags: windows, drawing

I'm looking for a Windows library that can draw musical notes on the screen in some way. I'm going to use it to write an app in C#, but a pure Win32-based solution is good enough. Does anybody know of any such library?

Edit: I'm going to update the notes in real-time, and they need not look incredibly fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

http://www.archiwistykamuzyczna.pl/index.php?article=download&lang=en#psamcontrollibrary

It's a simple library written in C# for displaying notes. It is limited to only one stave but it supports many voices on one stave. The input format is MusicXml but you can add notes programatically too.

Here is an article about PSAM Control Library on CodeProject:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/psamcontrollibrary.aspx

Comment: There's a new version here: http://manufaktura-programow.pl/En

Answer (score 8):

You will definitely want to look into [**Lilypond**](http://lilypond.org/web/), widely acknowledged as the best choice for musical typesetting. It's open-source and has all kinds of output formats, and is highly scriptable. It would be pretty easy to write your own C# wrapper around it. Example output:

[image]
<sub>(source: [lilypond.org](http://lilypond.org/web/images/engraver-score.png))</sub>

Comment: Looks nice, but it seems incredibly complex. I guess generating a C# wrapper around it would mean generating a description file, invoking lilypond, and then draw the results. If nothing better shows up, I might do this.

Comment: Try asking the lilypond-user mailing list. They can probably help you with more specific advice. http://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lilypond-user

Comment: LilyPond is indeed well scriptable, but is definitely not real time (also it IS incredibly fancy :)).

Answer (score 3):

Use [MusicXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicXML). There is [C++ binding](http://libmusicxml.sourceforge.net/).

[Rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/) can export MusicXML to PDF or PS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract relevant code from [Rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/), although it's very Qt-specific.