# Drawing music notes in android app

Tags: android, music-notation

I'm trying to make an app which has some music instruments to play with. When I play the instrument, the app will draw the music note by following the tempo. The video shown is what I'm trying to put into my app.

[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgCx2z5-Gzs)

Now, I'm trying to draw the music note in my app. Any idea how can I make it?

Comment: Read this question .... Seems something of similar sort. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670906/library-for-drawing-musical-notes?rq=1

Comment: @vincentsiau The video isn't available on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

There's a C# multiplatform music drawing engine Manufaktura Libraries: http://manufaktura-programow.pl/En
You can combine it with Xamarin (http://xamarin.com/) and make Android implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Can create a custom view:

```
class StaffView extends View {
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { // ... }
}
```

Draw the staff lines and use `SVG` or `PNG` image formats of the Clef, black note, white note, whole note, flat, sharp to draw on the staff with offsets.